# MagentoEE CMS Hierarchy Menu in Header

Tags: magento, content-management-system, enterprise

Using Magento EE, I have created a CMS Hierarchy (Admin > CMS > Pages > Manage Hierarchy). Each of the hierarchy items are set to `Show in Navigation Menu > Yes` under `Page Navigation Menu Options`. I would like to use this page hierarchy as a separate navigation menu in my header (as a super header navigation of sorts). The hierarchy must be its own separate menu, not part of the categories top menu.

In my local.xml layout, I have added a hierarchy menu block to my header, where I will be calling the hierarchy_menu template from:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        ...
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="enterprise_cms/hierarchy_menu" name="hierarchy_menu" template="cms/hierarchy/menu.phtml" />
        </reference>
        ...
    </default>
</layout>
```

In my page/html/header.phtml template, I am echoing the block:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hierarchy_menu') ?>
```

My issue is that the hierarchy menu block is rendering on CMS pages ONLY. On non-CMS pages, this block either halts the rendering of the rest of the page or simply does not render the menu. I can't seem to figure out why this is occurring. I would like to be able to render the `cms/hierarchy/menu.phtml` block in the site header on every page.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this a while back,   I still have yet to find an answer.  But I did find one the main reasons why it does not work.    The code for Enterprise CMS Hierarchy,  starts by determining which CMS page you are currently on.  So problem the main problem, you are in the header and not on a CMS page. Without having a current page to reference it will not work.  Please if you come across a solution please let me know. But this is at least a start as to why it doesnt work.

Comment: Thank you Rob for the insight. In digging in to the code a bit I completely agree with your explanation. Using a CMS hierarchy in a site-wide context probably wasn't its intended use, which is a bit of a shame, the feature would be extremely useful otherwise.

Comment: I agree, I have a 45 store setup that all uses the same content in varying ways.  It would be so nice to populate my cms content dynamically in the header using the built in cms tool.    Hopefully someone can chime in and shed some light on this.  It sucks creating a hierarchy and then having to hard code it into the my navigation menu on that particular store.

Comment: Bar, I have this working through a custom module. Right now it's in the beginning stages and really rough code, but once I'm done I'll come back and post my findings and code examples